# Create VM from VMDK in VMware using Ansible

Tags: ansible, vmware, vmdk

I could create VM in VMware from existing VMDK from Vsphere client. But I am not able to create it using Ansible. Can anyone suggest how to create VM from existing VMDK with Ansible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, you can't do it out of the box with Ansible.

I edited `vsphere_guest` module to be able to accomplish this for my client.
Unfortunately I can't disclose this custom module's code.

You need to modify [add_disk](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/986765312f65b03b62799cbb2fc32f82d0f02493/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/vmware/vsphere_guest.py#L360) method: remove `create` file operation and set existing VMDK filename for disk backing.